# Example Program for Error Message Address is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

as an practice for school I'm trying to find a program which produces the valgrind error `Address 0x1c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`. Of course there are lot of questions regarding this error but all of them are complete programs which are too big for my example.

Do you have a Tip for me how such an example program could look like?

Thx for your support

Comment: `int *p = (int *) 0x1c; *p = 0;`?

Comment: And *why* do you need such an example? What is the *real* problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can always cheat and free such a pointer explicitly:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (void)
{
  free ((void *) (uintptr_t) 0x1c);
  return 0;
}
```

A slightly more realistic example would be a null pointer dereference involving a struct member at offset 28.  Something like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct data
{
  int pad[7];
  int value;
};

int
main (void)
{
  volatile struct data *volatile pointer = NULL;
  pointer->value = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

(The `volatile` keywords are needed to prevent the compiler from recognizing the null pointer deference the dead store, and optimizing things accordingly.)